# Existe alguma forma de bloquear a renderização de um determinado componente no React?

Tags: javascript, react

Preciso bloquear a renderização de um certo tipo de componente, por exemplo:

```
<td>{props.children}</td>
```

Preciso capturar o componente que pode ser passado no children e bloquear sua renderização. Se eu quiser bloquear a tag p, como seria a forma de fazer isso? Existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: Você deseja bloquear assumindo que uma certa condição seja satisfeita? Poderia, por favor, detalhar um pouco mais a sua pergunta? :)

Comment: apenas não renderizar essa componente. Independente de condição.

Comment: Então só não o coloque na renderização.

Comment: então, a principio não tenho como controlar qu seja passado esse componente. Por isso a questão...

Answer (score 3):

Se você desejar filtrar algum elemento da `prop` `children` do React, você precisará usar a API `React.Children`:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Você pode, então, usar o método `React.Children.toArray()` para criar um *array* com base na propriedade `children` e filtrar somente os elementos que você desejar renderizar.

Para isso, já que estamos lidando com *array*, é conveniente usarmos o método [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).

Abaixo deixo um exemplo:

```js
function Container(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Componentes renderizados:</p>
      <hr />
      {React.Children.toArray(props.children).filter(
        (child) => child.type !== 'h2'
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h1>[h1] Este componente será renderizado.</h1>
      <h2>[h2] Este componente NÃO será renderizado.</h2>
      <h3>[h3] Este componente tanbém será renderizado.</h3>
    </Container>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Referência:

- [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren);
- [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).

Comment: Valeu, Luiz. Resolvi de outra forma, mas fica a dica. Obg :D

Comment: Legal! Posso saber como você fez? :)